# ORA-01001 Invalid Cursor error in function used in sql statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, sys-refcursor

I am getting ORA-01001 Invalid Cursor error in function pipe_cursor when i try to get the results and I can't figure it out why.

TYPE T_TBL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_TBL" as table of varchar2(36);
```

Test package:

```
create or replace package HOA_TEST is

 FUNCTION pipe_cursor(
                p_cur SYS_REFCURSOR
                ) RETURN t_tbl PIPELINED;

end HOA_TEST;
/
create or replace package body hoa_test is

  function pipe_cursor(p_cur in sys_refcursor) return t_tbl
    pipelined is
    v_ret rowid;
  begin

    if p_cur%isopen
    then

      loop
        fetch p_cur
          into v_ret;
        exit when p_cur%notfound;
        pipe row(v_ret);
      end loop;

      close p_cur;

    end if;

  end;

end hoa_test;
/
```

Test script:

```
declare 
  v_cur_newfilter SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  open v_cur_newfilter for select 1 from dual;
  open :cur for select column_value from table(HOA_TEST.pipe_cursor(v_cur_newfilter));
end;
```

NOTE:

If i call the function as

```
open :cur for select column_value from table(HOA_TEST.pipe_cursor(CURSOR(Select 1 from dual)));
```

it works

I am trying to do this on
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit